# How can I stretch a Border inside a Button?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am writing a form for a WPF app, and I'd like to use the visual states that `Button` offers. So my XAML is like this right now:

```
<Button
    Grid.Column="0"
    Name="GenderMaleButton"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    BorderThickness="0"
    Padding="0">
    <Border
        Background="White"
        BorderThickness="2"
        CornerRadius="5"
        Padding="5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock/>
    </Border>
</Button>
```

But my `Border` is not filling my `Button`. How can I make the `Border` fill the `Button`? Or how can I use the visual states of the `Button` to affect the `Border` in another way than wrapping the `Border` inside the `Button`?

Or can I apply visual states to my `Border`? If so, how?

EDIT: the result I want is like this:

[image: result]

So a selected state (white border, blue bg), and a default state (blue border, white bg).

Comment: Can you show a picture, how do you expect to see your button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a hard guess , I think you need to fill the border inside the button.Try the code below.Use ControlTemplate

```
<Button Grid.Column="0"
        Name="GenderMaleButton"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Padding="0">

        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>                
                <Border Background="#6A6B9A"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        CornerRadius="5"
                        Padding="5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" Text="Male"></TextBlock>
                </Border>              
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: This should work, but I don't want to use hard-coded width and height values, as my app needs to adapt to different screen sizes.

Comment: That seems nice, brb going to test this. I did not know that this was possible.

Answer (score 1):

You should have set `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

```
<Button
Grid.Column="0"
Name="GenderMaleButton"
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
BorderThickness="0"
Padding="0">
    <Border
    Background="White"
    BorderThickness="2"
    CornerRadius="5"
    Padding="5"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock/>
    </Border>
</Button>
```

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to actually stretch it for me... Might work for OP though?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<StackPanel Height="40" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="GenderButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="InternalBorder"
                                    CornerRadius="5"
                                    Padding="5">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="InternalText"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Male">
                                    <Setter TargetName="InternalBorder" Property="Background" Value="RoyalBlue" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="InternalText" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="Female">
                                    <Setter TargetName="InternalBorder" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="InternalBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="RoyalBlue" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="InternalBorder" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="InternalText" Property="Foreground" Value="RoyalBlue" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <!--  Whatever you want  -->
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <!--  Whatever you want  -->
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <Button x:Name="MaleButton"
                Content="Male"
                Style="{StaticResource GenderButtonStyle}"
                Tag="Male" />
        <Button x:Name="FemaleButton"
                Margin="5,0,0,0"
                Content="Female"
                Style="{StaticResource GenderButtonStyle}"
                Tag="Female" />
    </StackPanel>
```

To explain what I've done; I placed two buttons inside a horizontal `<StackPanel/>` and in its resources subtag I've made a Button Style that can then be assigned to any button you want.
Inside that style I've cracked open the Template and built my own small one that does what you described.

Generally, if a control isn't looking quite the way you want as-is, the best thing to do is open up the template it's made of and make your own.
Like this, you can now define what it should look like when you mouse-over or focus it or press it.